# .Net Core MVC in VS Code "server.Models" missing reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've started with a fresh

```
dotnet new mvc -o .
dotnet restore
```

Opening `Controllers/HomeController.cs` I'm seeing an error regarding the reference to another .cs file in the same project...

```
The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist 
in the namespace 'server' (are you missing an assembly 
reference?) [my-project]
```

I'm uncertain what the problem is... relatively new to .Net Core and using .Net via VS Code.

```
$ dotnet --version
2.1.201
```

### ~/Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using server.Models;

namespace server.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
      return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
  }
}
```

### ~/Models/ErrorViewModel.cs

```
using System;

namespace server.Models
{
  public class ErrorViewModel
  {
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
  }
}
```

-- 
UPDATE: Seems to be an issue witht he omniview service and that I have VSCode opened to a parent directory of my `server/` directory with the dotnet code.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to at least show us the code that is giving you this error and, since it's complaining about missing a `Models` namespace, prove that it exists inside your project.

Comment: @DavidG added code and an update/comment ... seems to be a VS Code / OmniSharp issue.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error right after using dto (data transfer object) at the top of HomeController.cs, for example

```
using dto = webapplication.Models;
```

In my situation, the solution was to add the prefix dto. to ErrorViewModel like this:

```
        public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new dto.ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

I think that using `server.Models;` in your example is causing the problem too. Hope this helps to solve it.